# eslint - Use array destructuring in my vue project

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I have a line like this `this.report = newVal[0];`. I'm looking at the documentation and I'm confused.

example I have seen are like

```
const local = this.propslocal
const {local} = this.props
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to change that at all?

Comment: What does eslint have to do with it, and what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: b/c we have a linter and it's throwing `Use array destructuring.eslint(prefer-destructuring)` error and I've looked at a bunch of examples but can't figure it out

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: [eslint prefer-destructuring rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring):

> This rule enforces usage of destructuring instead of accessing a
>   property through a member expression.

As the examples you have seen, you should change your:

```
this.report = newVal[0]
```

To this instead:

```
[this.report] = newVal;
```

To make it clear for you, if `newVal` has 4 items, and you want to store first 2 items into different variables, instead of doing:

```
const a = newVal[0];
const b = newVal[1];
```

Using destructuring, you should do:

```
const [a, b] = newVal;
```